# How to access project name from a query of type portfolioitem

Tags: rally

I am trying to match Project name in my query and also trying to print the name of the project associated with each feature record. I know there are plenty of answers but I couldn't find anything that could help me. I am trying to do something like this:

```
pi_query.type = "portfolioitem"      
pi_query.fetch="Name,FormattedID,Owner,c_ScopingTeam,c_AspirationalRelease,c_AssignedProgram,Tags"

#To be configured as per requirement
pi_query.project_scope_up = false
pi_query.project_scope_down = false
pi_query.order = "FormattedID Asc"


pi_query.query_string = "(Project.Name = \"Uni - Serviceability\")"
pi_results = @rally.find(pi_query)
```

I am trying to match the project name but it simply doesn't work, I also tried printing the name of the project, i tried Project.Name, Project.Values or simply Project. But it doesn't work. I am guessing it is because of my query type which is "portfolioItem" and I can't change my type because I am getting all other attribute values correctly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to fetch Project, e.g: `feature_query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID,Project"`

and this should work:

`feature_query.query_string = "(Project.Name = \"My Project\")"`

Here is an example where a feature is found by project name.

```
require 'rally_api'

#Setup custom app information
headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()
headers.name = "create story in one project, add it to a feature from another project"
headers.vendor = "Nick M RallyLab"
headers.version = "1.0"

# Connection to Rally
config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username] = "user@co.com"
config[:password] = "secret"
config[:workspace] = "W"
config[:project] = "Product1"
config[:headers] = headers #from RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()

@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

obj = {}
obj["Name"] = "new story xyz123"
new_s = @rally.create("hierarchicalrequirement", obj)

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = "portfolioitem"
query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID,Project"
query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/12352608129" } 
query.query_string = "(Project.Name = \"Team Group 1\")"

result = @rally.find(query)
feature = result.first

puts feature

field_updates={"PortfolioItem" => feature}
new_s.update(field_updates)
```

Comment: "Project.Name" doesn't work in my case, is it because you are creating type "hierarchicalrequirement" while mine is "portfolioitem"?

Comment: I query on feature: `query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = "portfolioitem"
query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID,Project"
query.query_string = "(Project.Name = \"Team Group 1\")"` Creation of a story in this code is incidental. Looks like you do not fetch Project in your code.